# Are non-implemented abstract methods a design flaw?

Tags: php, oop

Here is an example of my class structure for a data mapping pattern (simplified). Notice that the save and find methods are technically implemented in the concrete class, but do not do anything yet. What alternatives are there to avoid this? One option I am currently using is an abstract DataMapperAbstract class that implements the interface, throws an exception for every method, then all concrete data mappers only have to implement the functions they use - it just smells bad. Personally, I have thought of creating a separate interface for each method (DataMapper_FindInterface, DataMapper_SaveInterface, DataMapper_DeleteInterface, etc.) but it seems a bit smelly.

```
    interface DataMapperInterface
    {
            public function find($params);
            public function save($object);
            public function delete($object);
    }

    class DataMapper_User implements DataMapperInterface
    {                               
            public function find($params)
            {                       
                    //Execute code to retrieve data from data source
                    return someDataRetrievalMethod($params);
            }

            public function save($object)
            {
                    throw new Exception('Method not yet implemented.');
            }

            public function delete($object)
            {
                    throw new Exception('Method not yet implemented.');
            }
    }
```

Comment: If it's method not *yet* implemented, then it's ok. It's a temporary missing feature. Eventually, you'll add it. If not, then I'd say it's a pretty big flaw. If nothing else, because there's no way for the class user to detect if a feature is supported. I'd either create an extra interface or add the methods "canSave"/"canDelete".

Comment: @luiscubal Good idea .. provide an abstract class for `canSave\canDelete` with `false` value would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not in the class that has al methods implement, make the class abstract.

Abstract classes can not be instantiated, and there must be another class thats extends the abstract class with a implementation.

So your code so far would look like this:

```
    interface DataMapperInterface
    {
            public function find($params);
            public function save($object);
            public function delete($object);
    }

    abstract class DataMapper_User implements DataMapperInterface
    {                               
            public function find($params)
            {                       
                    //Execute code to retrieve data from data source
                    return someDataRetrievalMethod($params);
            }

    }
```

Comment: The DataMapper_User is the final class that will be instantiated, but even if I did extend an <<abstract>> DataMapper_User, PHP will throw a fatal error: `contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods `. Therefore, I will still be forced to implement the methods, even though they won't do anything.

Comment: I want to enforce the public find, save, delete methods, but not require that they be implemented - some of our data mappers need only be responsible for some of the three tasks. Eventually, we want them to be responsible for all, but we are in a long term migration from system to system.